# Defining Alphabetical Characters As Other Alphabetical Characters In C++

Tags: c++

Here is what I am trying to do. I have an array of the alphabets.

```
char defaultCharacters[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', ...., 'Z'};
```

So what i wanna do is the following.
Lets say the user wanted 8char indentation, so the letter 'A' will be 'I'.
Basically A+8 .

Any idea of what should I do because I dont want to define each letter as another it will take alot of time. Thanks!

Comment: You can do this `char defaultCharacters[] = "ABCDE...Z";` - Makes the code a bit easier to read

Comment: And what should happen with `'Z' + 8`?

Comment: Think for a while... the character `'A'` is at index zero. What would happen if you add `8` to `0`? What index do you get then, and what character is on that index? As for the end, think about the *modulo operator*.

Comment: @Danny_ds It reloops back to 'A' and so on. So basically Z+8 = 'H' if you do NOT count 'A' as 0

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks buddy !

Comment: @Vancer _"It reloops back to 'A'  ..."_ Restrict the index with a modulo.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg True, you would get 8.. So simply 8 is 'I'

Comment: If you take a look at [ASCII table](http://ascii.cl/), you can get rid of the array at all.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Thanks!

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Only works for ASCII encoding, or other encodings where the letters are encoded consecutively. Won't work for e.g. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) encoding (which can still be found "in the wild").

Comment: @Joachim: but who uses EBCDIC today? ASCII is de-facto standard, and many other modern encodings are it's supersets.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus True it's not common, but that and other encodings *do* exists, and the C++ standard doesn't require letters to be encoded consecutively. So using an array (and to the OP, remember that a string literal is an array as well) and using the indexes is the only true portable way to handle this. And as a side-note, the C++ specification do require digits to be encoded consecutively, so using e.g. `someDigitCharacter - '0'` is well-defined and supported.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Who uses ASCII today? It's best to know exactly which character set and encoding you are using.

Comment: @Vancer You've described the alphabet, in uppercase, for English. Are sure that your input will only contain such letters. There are a lot more letters used in texts, including English texts.

Comment: @Tom: directly, probably almost no-one uses ASCII today. But, AFAIK, many modern encodings are supersets of ASCII.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
char oldchar = 'A'; // check for a valid char from 'A' to 'Z'
char newchar = defaultCharacters[(oldchar + 8 - 'A') % 26];
```

But you'll need to check for a valid `oldchar` first.

Comment: You need to subtract the value of `A` to get the index correct

Comment: @EdHeal - Indeed - fixed, thanks. Also needs a check for negative values as well (`oldchar = '*'` for example).

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

```
char defaultCharacters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH";
char new_char = defaultCharacters[old_char + 8 - 'A'];
```

or

```
char new_char = 'A' + (old_char + 8 - 'A') % 26;
```

But first of all `old_char` should be checked i.e.

```
if (old_char < 'A' || old_char > 'Z') { .... some error code
} else {
   ....
```

Comment: You need the modulo operation to get the required wrap around correct.

Comment: I added an additional 8 characters to the end so the modulo operation is not required

Comment: @Vancer - Do not understand the comment

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart), you don't need your *array of the alphabets* at all:

```
const char input = std::cin.get();
const char output = (input - 'A' + 8) % 26 + 'A';
```